# wxWidgets (static lib) will not link under VC++ 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, wxwidgets

I cannot get a wxWidgets program that uses the wxWidgets static libraries to compile and link properly under VC++ 2010. Under VC++ 2008, it's fine. (WxWidgets still ships with vc++ 2008 project files.)

I compiled and ran the "minimal" sample program that comes with wxWidgets. It is a GUI hello world. No problem. I used VC++ 2010 to convert the .vsproj to .vsxproj and attempt to compile and link under VC++ 2010. Problem.

Be assured that I changed absolutely nothing other than to run the VC++ 2010 conversion to create minimal.vsxproj.

I got many linker warnings and errors, all having to do with STL wchar_t strings in the wxWidgets libs. Here is what I think is happening. I believe there must be #ifdefs in the wxWidgets code that select __declspec(import) or not, based on preprocessor symbols. When VC++ 2010 converted the project, it must have changed the symbols to something that fools wxWidgets. If so, the bug could be in either place, either wxWidgets is making invalid assumptions about pre-processor definitions, or the VC++ 2010 conversion messed them up.
The command lines for compiling the lone .cpp file in the project differ more than I would expect them to.

*2008 command line*

> /Od /I ".....\lib\vc_lib\mswud" /I ".....\include" /I "." /I
>   ".....\samples" /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D
>   "_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE=1" /D "_CRT_NON_CONFORMING_SWPRINTFS=1" /D
>   "_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS=1" /D "**WXMSW**" /D "_UNICODE" /D "_WINDOWS"
>   /D "NOPCH" /D "UNICODE" /FD /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /Fo"vc_mswud\minimal\"
>   /Fd"vc_mswud\minimal.pdb" /W4 /nologo /c /Zi /TP /errorReport:prompt 
>   /MP

*2010 command line*

> /I".....\lib\vc_lib\mswud" /I".....\include" /I"."
>   /I".....\samples" /Zi /nologo /W4 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D "WIN32" /D
>   "_DEBUG" /D "_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE=1" /D
>   "_CRT_NON_CONFORMING_SWPRINTFS=1" /D "_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS=1" /D
>   "**WXMSW**" /D "_UNICODE" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "NOPCH" /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1
>   /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /GR
>   /Fp"vc_mswud\minimal\minimal.pch" /Fa"vc_mswud\minimal\"
>   /Fo"vc_mswud\minimal\" /Fd"vc_mswud\minimal.pdb" /Gd /analyze-
>   /errorReport:queue

*Example 2010 warning and error*

```
1>wxbase29ud.lib(ipcbase.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol ??1?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@QAE@XZ (public: __thiscall std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> >::~basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> >(void)) imported

1>wxbase29ud.lib(mimecmn.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > & __thiscall std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> >::assign(class std::_String_const_iterator<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> >,class std::_String_const_iterator<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> >)" (__imp_?assign@?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@QAEAAV12@V?$_String_const_iterator@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@2@0@Z)
```

Comment: Build wxWidgets from source code using VS2010.

Comment: @Alex I tried that initially, before I built it with 2008. I ran into the same problem multiplied by 1000. I have found no wxWidgets library project files for 2010. When I convert a 2008, to 2010 no joy.

Comment: I build wxWidgets with 2010, converting existing wxWidgets-2.n.n\build\msw\wx.dsw to 2010 format. I even don't know what version it is, just double-click and convert to 2010. What problem exactly you have, building with VS2010?

Comment: @Alex Microsoft's conversion Wizard creates nonsensical names for targets and I-do-not-know-what-all, then at link time warns you that it cannot make sense of them. Sure enough, the project will not build properly. It takes a Master's degree in Microsoft obfuscation to figure out how to set it straight. I do not know how.

Comment: @Alex - I have no confidence that if I were to be able to convert the 2008 project files to properly constructed 2010 ones, it would make any difference. The libraries built fine under 2008. It is compiling the application under 2010 that is messing up. The compiled application thinks it wants things from a DLL. Changing how the library was compiled would not affect that. The things it thinks it wants from a DLL are invariably related to STL wchar_t strings.

Comment: Repairing the botched project files that the MS Wizard created would require tedious editing of the property pages of 23 projects - if I knew how.

Comment: BTW, Microsoft published an explanation of how why it made perfect sense for the Wizard to create a project file that it knew was probably unusable. It went on to explain how to fix the project, but I could not make heads or tails of the it. For starters, one must make a Rosetta Stone mapping entries in the Properties dialogs to names like $(Target). Of course they do not have the same names. That would make it too easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely **must** build wxWidgets and the application using it with the same version of the compiler, different MSVC versions use different, incompatible versions of the CRT and so there is no chance at all that you can use VC10 to build an application and link it with wxWidgets built with VC9.

As for building wx itself with VC10, there are indeed sometimes some problems when importing VC9 projects, the custom build rules can somehow be mangled. If this happens to you (although AFAIK nobody reported it for wx 2.9.4 project files yet), just copy the custom build rules for `setup.h` manually or simply execute them yourself manually.

FWIW we hope to have "native" VC10 and VC11 projects in 3.0 release (coming soon).

Comment: I do not know what means, "copy the custom build rules for setup.h" or "execute them yourself manually." All I know is that the MS Wizard does not create a valid .vsxproj files for the 23 projects. Are you suggesting to build without using the .vsxproj file and Visual Studio? Or is there some way to create the .vsxproj file without using the Wizard? Can you give the steps explicitly?

Comment: I got a fresh version of the sources and endeavored once again to build under VC++ 2010. This time things seem to have gone better. I have no idea why. It is conceivable that the VC++ Wizard changed with an auto-update. Whatever. Wx built all the projects except one on the first try. That one built on the second attempt. (Strange, eh?) There were hundreds of warnings, but I do appear to have .lib files. Maybe I am good now.

Comment: I didn't realize you didn't get any .vcxproj files at all, usually they're created just fine by the wizard but sometimes the custom build steps are not imported. Apparently something even worse happened in your case. Anyhow, glad to see the import did work better the next time.